# How to access a registrationService in a CustusX plugin?

Tags: plugins

In a custom plugin in custusX i use `mServices->patientModelService->getPatientLandmarks()->setLandmark` to programmatically alter some landmarks. I want to perform the registration with a already present volume.

In `LandmarkPatientRegistrationWidget` in `org.custusx.registration.method.landmark`, `performRegistration()` calls `mServices.registrationService->doPatientRegistration()`.

However, I'm not sure whether my approach to get hold of a `registrationService` instance is right.

I have so far added `org_custusx_registration` to the CMakeLists.txt file and added `"cxRegistrationService.h"` and `<cxRegServices.h>` as includes.

Now I can define a `RegServices mRegServices` and initialize it in the constructor with the `mContext` of the plugin.

But do I create an own registration service or do I get access to the already existing? How can I get access to the already running registration service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method correctly reuses the existing running registration service.

The default setup of CustusX register a *single instance* (object) implementing the [cx::RegistrationService](http://www.custusx.org/uploads/developer_doc/nightly/classcx_1_1_registration_service.html) interface. The [cx::RegServices](http://www.custusx.org/uploads/developer_doc/nightly/classcx_1_1_reg_services.html) helper class contains a [cx::RegistrationServiceProxy](http://www.custusx.org/uploads/developer_doc/nightly/classcx_1_1_registration_service_proxy.html), which acts as a smart pointer referring the object. Service objects are only created by the plugin that implement them: Users simply get access to these objects.

The RegistrationServiceProxy implements this using a [ctkServiceTracker](http://www.commontk.org/docs/html/classctkServiceTracker.html) and related classes, see for example [this tutorial on OSGi](http://www.knopflerfish.org/tutorials/osgi_tutorial.pdf), section 5.4 (in java, but the principles apply).